# RollbackException hides ValidationException

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jax-rs, bean-validation

I use JAX-RS to update an entity and I have a ValidationException mapper to handle validation errors.

In my JAX-RS method, I delegate the entity's update to an EJB method that uses internally EntityManager#merge to do the job.

Everything works fine but when I have a validation constraint error, instead of having a ValidationException which is then handled by my JAX-RS wrapper, I have instead a RollbackException which wraps my ValidationException. Therefore my exception wrapper is not called.

I thought of several ways to fix that :

- validate my entity in the JAX-RS method before calling my EJB
- flush my entity manager in the EJB method then catch the rollback in the JAX-RS method, "unwrap" the validation exception and throw it.
- etc.

I am looking for the best way to handle such problem. How would you do that ?

Thanks,

F.D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the mapper approach and all changes are made via JAX-RS, I'll probably use JAX-RS Bean Validation support. You might then even be able to disable the JPA life-cycle based validation (using 'validation-mode' NONE).

In the end it will come down to how your application is structured and what your preferences are.